# What data structure does a SQL query return in python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I would like to calculate the 'totalStock' but I am getting a typeError because p['stockValue'] is not an integer. I have tried to use the int() function but it also does not work.

```
    def index():
    # Get user ID
    user_ID = session['user_id']

    # Query for symbol, name, shares and store in variable
    purchaseData = db.execute('SELECT symbol, name, shares FROM purchases WHERE id = :id', id=user_ID)

    #Store all info in userData
    userData = {}
    stockCount = 0
    for i in purchaseData:
        userData['symbol'] = i['symbol']
        userData['name'] = i['name']
        userData['shares'] = i['shares']
        userData['price'] = lookup(i['symbol'])
        # Calculate stock value
        userData['stockValue'] = lookup(i['symbol']) * i['shares']
        # Count rows
        stockCount += 1

    # Query for remaining cash
    userData['remainingCash'] = db.execute('SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :id', id=user_ID)

    # Calculate total value
    totalStock = 0
    for p in userData:
        totalStock = totalStock + int(p['stockValue'])

    userData['totalValue'] = userData['remainingCash'] + totalStock

    # Return render and send values
    return render_template('index.html', rows=stockCount, **userData)
```

What is the structure of purchaseData?

Comment: Please fix the indentation and show a [mre].

Comment: You can find out the type of any object `x` by printing `type(x)`.

Comment: Isnt this `lookup(i['symbol'])` a text value? How can you multiply it by shares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has all the distinguishing characteristics of a CS50 Finance project. From [the spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/tracks/web/finance/):

> `lookup`, [is] a function that, given a `symbol` (e.g., NFLX), returns a stock
> quote for a company in the form of a `dict` with three keys: `name`, whose
> value is a `str`, the name of the company; `price`, whose value is a
> `float`; and `symbol`, whose value is a `str`, a canonicalized (uppercase)
> version of a stock’s symbol, irrespective of how that symbol was
> capitalized when passed into `lookup`

Comment: I think I have fixed the error involving the lookup function but I am still getting an error in the line: 
totalStock = totalStock + p['stockValue'].
I have tried to make totalStock a float but that doesn't seem to work either. And yes, this is the CS50 Finance project in the web track.

Comment: Maybe it needs to be "fixed" a different way to get the correct result :)  You can edit the changes into the question.